# Material UI - How to clip drawer under the appbar with relative position

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using React Material UI version `4.3.1`. I'm trying to setup the Drawer component so that it's clipped under the AppBar component. There are a lot of examples online but all of them is written with the AppBar component in a fixed position at the top of the window. How can I get the drawer applied to the AppBar that has `position="relative"` property?

In my case, I will have a site header at the top of the screen, which is not part of the material ui. That's why the AppBar component needed to be positioned relatively so that it doesn't show over the site header. The AppBar will be rendered below the site header and I'd like to add the Drawer component from that position also.

Has anyone used the appbar and the drawer component in the above scenario?